# ¿como hacer una matriz del 0,8 de forma aleatoria?

Tags: python, python-3.x

lo que pasa es que necesito hacer una matriz, lista etc. de 3x3 que imprima del 0 al 8 en diferentes posiciones. y que no se repitan los numeros.

```
    from random import *
    fil=3
    col=3
    a = [[randint(0,8)for i in range(fil)] for j in range(col)]
    for f in a:
    print (f)
```

me imprime algo asi:

```
   [3, 1, 6]
   [1, 1, 4]
   [4, 8, 1]
```

y quiero que me quede asi:

```
   (7, 3, 5)
   (4, 0, 6)
   (2, 1, 8)
```

que no se repitan los números.
algunos temas que estudiar??

Comment: Haz una lista del 0 al 8, desordénala, y toma los números en el orden en que te vengan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no quieres repeticiones la forma más simple es obtener una lista aplanada con todos los items desordenados, luego agrupas para obtener la matriz:

Para obtener la lista aplanada con números desordenados de `0` a `N` sin repetición puedes hacer uso de `range` y `random.sample`:

```
import random


def matriz_aleatoria(filas,  columnas):
    n = filas * columnas
    aleatorios = random.sample(range(0,  n),  n)
    return [aleatorios[i: i + columnas] for i in range(0,  n, columnas)]
```

> ```
> >>> matriz = matriz_aleatoria(3,  3)
> [[0, 3, 5], [7, 1, 6], [8, 4, 2]]
> ```